# Why my \fontspec can't work on Chinese characters?

Tags: fonts, fontspec

When I want to change a Chinese font, I use the `\fontspec` command. However this command only worked for the English part. Here is my code and the output.

```latex
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\fontspec{FZYaoTi} Hello World. 对中文无效
\end{document}
```

[image]

I should clarify that I didn't get any errors even warnings. My problem is my Chinese characters didn't change their font.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "can't work". Are you getting any error messages? If so, what to they say?

Comment: No, I didn't get any errors even warnings! "can't work" means that my Chinese character didn't change their font.

Comment: The documentation for the class you’re using is in Chinese, which I unfortunately cannot read, but to the best of my knowledge, you should be using the commands `\setCJKmainfont`, `\setCJKsansfont`, `\setCJKmonofont` and `\setCJKmathfont` with `ctex`.

Comment: Another option is to use a different document class (such as `article`), with `babel`, which supports Chinese. It even lets you use multiple East Asian languages simultaneously. I’m more familiar with that package.

Comment: ctexart contains code to switch to specific cjk fonts for chinese, read the documentation how to change the fontset.